# Spring Boot could not autowire and run

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-boot, autowired

I am unable to run the [attached Spring Boot sampler application](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_ws0yWyg96JYXZKWUdoU1VlUkE/view?usp=sharing). It has an AMQP starter, requiring RabbitMQ. Fundamentally, it is a simple application that just sends a message to a RabbitMQ Exchange with a queue bound to it. I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.company.messaging.MessageDeliveryManager com.company.exec.Application.messageDeliveryManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.company.messaging.MessageDeliveryManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
 {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

**Application.java**

```
package com.company.exec;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

  @Autowired
  MessageDeliveryManager messageDeliveryManager;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    messageDeliveryManager.sendMessage(String message);
  }
}
```

**MessageDeliveryManager.java**

```java
package com.company.messaging;

public interface MessageDeliveryManager {
  void sendMessage(String message);
}
```

**MessageDeliveryImpl.java**

```java
package com.company.messaging;

public class MessageDeliveryManagerImpl implements MessageDeliveryManager {

  @Value("${app.exchangeName}")
  String exchangeName;

  @Value("${app.queueName}")
  String queueName;

  @Autowired
  RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

  @Bean
  Queue queue() {
    return new Queue(queueName, false);
  }

  @Bean
  DirectExchange exchange() {
    return new DirectExchange(exchangeName);
  }

  @Bean
  Binding binding(Queue queue, DirectExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(queueName);
  }

  public void sendMessage(String message) {
    rabbitTemplate.send(queueName, message);
  }
}
```

I would really appreciate if someone can review and provide a suggestion on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What does this MessageDeliveryManager class has? I think the error is caused by some other bean failure. Can you see other error messages related to RMQ?

Comment: `MessageDeliveryManager` is an interface, implemented by `MessageDeliveryManagerImpl`. The Impl class implements the method defined by the contract and is annotated by `@Service`.

Comment: Please add the interface `MessageDeliveryManager` and the implemantation of this interface and class `Application` to your questaion.

Comment: Is the package that the `MessageDeliveryManagerImpl` is in, scanned by Spring Boot? If not the bean isn't available in the context.

Comment: @Jens since I attached the project source code, I didn't paste the code in the question. I will still add it. Thanks for making the suggestion.

Comment: @M.Deinum the question was answered. Problem was that component scanning was scanning only the current package where `Application.java` resided and not the sibling packages. I used the suggestion to move this file higher up the hierarchy and scanning covered all child packages. The other suggestion was to explicitly specify the starting point in the package hierarchy as an argument to the `@ComponentScan` annotation, which also tested fine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you have a package tree like this:

```
com.company.exec
com.company.messaging
```

and just use a default `@SpringBootApplication`, it just doesn't see your `MessageDeliveryManager` and its implementation. That's because `@ComponentScan` (the meta-annotation on the `@SpringBootApplication`) does a scan only for the current package and its subpackages.

To make it worked you should add this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.company")
```

Or just move your `Application` to the root package - `com.company`.

Comment: _does a scan only for the current package_ is not accurate. All packages starting with `com.company.exec` would be scanned. In this case there is only one, though.

Comment: How do I override the virtual host, host, user name and password properties when using Boot's `RabbitAutoConfiguration`?

Comment: See Boot documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html. Search for `RABBIT`